# Oracle APEX Change default columns order in Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an issue with changing interactive grid default column order. My APEX version 19.2

If i change order in Columns nothing change. If i change order in SqlQuery nothing change. If I rearrange Columns Using Drag and Drop and i disconnect and reconnect from my application, the order of columns return as before.

I'm doing wrong or there is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- run the IG page
- click the "Actions" button

  - select "Columns" from the menu
  - using up/down buttons in the lower left corner, rearrange columns
  - once you're done, click "Save" button
- once again click "Actions"

  - select "Report"
  - click "Save" (which will save default report settings)